# IA Fraca, conceito e exemplo no desenvolvimento de software

Tags: inteligência-artificial, machine-learning, deep-learning

A IA Fraca diz respeito a construção de software de certa forma inteligente. Toda lógica processada por um computador pode ser considerada como IA Fraca? ou só se enquadra dentro desta categoria aquelas estruturas que vemos ou ouvimos falar nessa disciplina, Por exemplo: Algoritmos Genéticos, Redes Neurais, etc...

Iniciante em IA

Answer (score 1):

P: Toda lógica processada por um computador pode ser considerada como IA Fraca?

R: Não. "A ciência da computação define a pesquisa da IA como o estudo de 'agentes inteligentes': qualquer dispositivo que perceba seu ambiente e realize ações que maximizem sua chance de atingir seus objetivos com sucesso." - [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence)

Dessa forma, é fácil perceber que dentro dessa definição, os algoritmos comuns não podem ser considerados IA, pois faltam um ou vários dos elementos que a compõe: Percepção; Acionabilidade; Objetivos e -- subentendido em "maximizem sua chance de atingir seus objetivos com sucesso", uma função de adequação (*fitness function*).

Todavia, é importante notar que em algumas definições, termos como "aprendizado", "tomada de decião", "interpretação de dados" e "cognição" -- por exemplo, são extremamente mal empregados e boa parte não é nem totalmente compreendida em seres humanos, enquanto outros nem fazem sentido. Um bom ponto de partida é Consciousness: An Introduction
da Susan Blackmore. Você acha por aí =]